# Why PMD basic rulesets does not capture null dereference?

Tags: java, pmd

I am using   `PMD Plug-in 3.2.6.v2009033006`  . But the default rulesets in pmd is not captured possible null pointer exception .

**Java Code**

```
public class SignUp extends HttpServlet{
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res){
        String user = req.getParameter("user");
        user.trim(); 
     }
}
```

`user.trim();` if the `user` variable is null it will be prone to null pointer exception . I checked my code with pmd but it will not indicate this ?
How can i capture this ? . Is there any custom pmd ruleset is available?

Is there any custom rulesets available for capturing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMD isn't the right tool for this. You should use FindBugs to catch such problems.

But even with FindBugs, you won't catch anything because the above code is perfectly reasonable, and doesn't have any bug, unless you know that `getParameter("user")` can return null, and that there is something better to do than throwing a NullPointerException in this case.

If such code triggered an error, basically every line of code which calls a method on an object returned by another method would trigger an error. FindBugs supports annotations that allows declaring that the caller of a method should always check for null on the result returned by this method. See http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html. But of course, for third-party code, you can't do anything (other than writing your own rules).